# How to make a call which begin with * in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, phone-number, url-scheme, phone-call

In my application, I want to call the number *111, when I use this URL tel:*111 to call, but can't make call success, please give me some indicate, thank you very much.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"tel:*111"]
```

was not work. but it will work when remove `*`:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"tel:111"];
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible. From the [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1):

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone application supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.