# Swift's openURL method does not place a phone call with an Asterix sign (iOS 8.4)

Tags: ios, swift, phone-number, phone-call, openurl

I'm trying to place a PhoneCall in a swift application. 
It works pretty simple with regular phone numbers using the openURL
method.  However, when I try to use a string that contains an asterix (for example, dial the number (****02), the method returns false. 
I've tried using string literals with no help.

Is it possible to do so at all?  Thanks!

```
    var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://****02")!
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a call which begin with \* in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956692/how-to-make-a-call-which-begin-with-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

[Phone Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html)

> ... To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or
>   changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone app supports
>   most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme.
>   **Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app
>   does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.** ...

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading an answer from somebody that Apple doesn't allow you to dial numbers that contain "*" or "#". If I remember the thread correctly, the rationale was that those let you do things like log in to automated phone systems, and that should be under the user's control.

Comment: Thanks! Damn. So it is not possible whatsoever?

Comment: No, it's not possible.